# Division of page into 6

Tags: html, css

I am currently developing my skills page on my portfolio and was wondering if anyone could explain how I was to have 6 sections on my page, 3 sections on top and 3 on the bottom, preferably without having to create a scrollbar and keeping it all nice a flush on one page but if not then not to worry. I will supply my code and an example of my page below. Any information would help a lot. Thank you in advance.

Example of the page[image]

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<div class="split left">
  <div class="centered">
    <img src="Assets/coding.png" alt="Online World">
    <h2>Website Developer</h2>
    <div class="svg-wrapper">
      <svg height="40" width="150" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
        <rect id="shape" height="40" width="150" />
        <div id="text">
          <a href="web.html"><span class="spot"></span>Learn More</a>
        </div>
      </svg>
  </div>    
  </div>
</div>


  <div class="split center">
      <div class="centered">
        <img src="Assets/technician.png" alt="Online World">
        <h2>ICT Technician</h2>
        <div class="svg-wrapper">
          <svg height="40" width="150" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
            <rect id="shape" height="40" width="150" />
            <div id="text">
              <a href="web.html"><span class="spot"></span>Learn More</a>
            </div>
          </svg>
      </div>    
      </div>
    </div>

 <div class="split right">
      <div class="centered">
        <img src="Assets/shield.png" alt="Security">
        <h2>Security Analyst</h2>
        <div class="svg-wrapper">
          <svg height="40" width="150" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
            <rect id="shape" height="40" width="150" />
            <div id="text">
              <a href="web.html"><span class="spot"></span>Learn More</a>
            </div>
    </svg>
  </div>      
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.split {
 color: white;
 font-family: sans-serif;
 height: 100%;
 width: 33.33%;
 position: fixed;
 top: 0;
 overflow-x: hidden;
 padding-top: 0px;
}

.left { 
  left: 0;
  background: #0F2027; 
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #0F2027, #080e10);
}

.left h2 {
    color: aliceblue;
    font-family: sans-serif;
}

.right h2 {
    color: aliceblue;
    font-family: sans-serif;
}
.center {
  left:33%;
  right:33%;
  background: #0F2027; 
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #0F2027, #080e10);
}

.right {
  right: 0;
  background: #0F2027; 
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #0F2027, #080e10);
}

.centered {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  text-align: center;
}

.centered img {
  width: 150px;
}
```

Comment: you could use bootstrap to assist you? and manually calculate the height of the page?

Comment: Would you be able to provide some sort of example?

Comment: have you tried googling bootstrap?

Comment: I have but I am struggling a little, could you help? I am finding html to do what I want but no css to go along with it.

Comment: 3 sections on top and 3 on the bottom. So no continuous column right?

Comment: Correct, 3 on the top and 3 on the bottom

Comment: then mobile view?

Comment: Mobile view 1 on top of another

Answer (score 0):

This can be done using bootstrap column divisions :

```
<div class="row">
 <div class="col-md-4">
     <!-- Top Left Block code here -->
 </div>
 <div class="col-md-4">
     <!-- Top Center Block code here -->
 </div>
 <div class="col-md-4">
     <!-- Top right Block code here -->
 </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
 <div class="col-md-4">
     <!-- Bottom Left Block code here -->
 </div>
 <div class="col-md-4">
     <!-- Bottom Center Block code here -->
 </div>
 <div class="col-md-4">
     <!-- Bottom right Block code here -->
 </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I have used this and I get this as an output. https://gyazo.com/2f4838ad169f79bf075ccaf80e69db4d?token=d9cf8a9325f3d4e9963b1833fb61e460

Comment: I didn't find this being implemented at the given link

Answer (score 0):

you can do easily with the help of CSS grid

wrap everything inside of and div with class sections

```
<div class="sections"></div>
```

now define a class with

```
.sections{
display:grid;
grid-template-columns:1fr 1fr 1fr;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use Bootstrap to divide screen into 6 parts.
Refer below bootstrap code

```html
<html>

<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-4 col-xs-4" style="border:1px solid;">1</div>
      <div class="col-md-4 col-xs-4" style="border:1px solid;">2</div>
      <div class="col-md-4 col-xs-4" style="border:1px solid;">3</div>
      <div class="col-md-4 col-xs-4" style="border:1px solid;">4</div>
      <div class="col-md-4 col-xs-4" style="border:1px solid;">5</div>
      <div class="col-md-4 col-xs-4" style="border:1px solid;">6</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Added this to my code just to see if it would work and it appears off the bottom of the page, I think it may be something to do with my background but I am not sure.

https://gyazo.com/b49f3e1cdd3b775eed9bda5f4bff9b46

Comment: Don't mix your code with bootstrap code. Put all inner dives in bootstrap inner col divs.

Comment: Check your hierarchy of div once it will work properly and instead of 1 2 3 .. put proper data in div.

Answer (score 0):

I just edited your code. You can adjust the container height based on your requirement. First section will be on top and the second section will go on bottom based on body height. In mobile everything will be aligned one by one as per your reference. I hope this will work for you.

```css
body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    font-size: inherit;
}

.first-section {
    width: 100%;
    align-self: start;
}

.second-section {
    width: 100%;
    align-self: end;
}

.container {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    min-height: 500px;
}

.split {
    color: white;
    font-family: sans-serif;
    height: 100%;
    width: 33.33%;
    display: inline-block;
    float: left;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 20px 0;
}

.left {
    left: 0;
    background: #0F2027;
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #0F2027, #080e10);
}

.left h2 {
    color: aliceblue;
    font-family: sans-serif;
}

.right h2 {
    color: aliceblue;
    font-family: sans-serif;
}

.center {
    left: 33%;
    right: 33%;
    background: #0F2027;
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #0F2027, #080e10);
}

.right {
    right: 0;
    background: #0F2027;
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #0F2027, #080e10);
}

.centered img {
    width: 150px;
}

@media (max-width: 767px) {
    .container {
        display: block;
    }
    .split {
        width: 100%;
        float: none
    }
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
<div class="first-section">
 <div class="split left">
   <div class="centered">
  <img src="Assets/coding.png" alt="Online World">
  <h2>Website Developer</h2>
  <div class="svg-wrapper">
    <svg height="40" width="150" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
   <rect id="shape" height="40" width="150" />
   <div id="text">
     <a href="web.html"><span class="spot"></span>Learn More</a>
   </div>
    </svg>
   </div>    
   </div>
 </div>


   <div class="split center">
    <div class="centered">
   <img src="Assets/technician.png" alt="Online World">
   <h2>ICT Technician</h2>
   <div class="svg-wrapper">
     <svg height="40" width="150" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
    <rect id="shape" height="40" width="150" />
    <div id="text">
      <a href="web.html"><span class="spot"></span>Learn More</a>
    </div>
     </svg>
    </div>    
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="split right">
    <div class="centered">
   <img src="Assets/shield.png" alt="Security">
   <h2>Security Analyst</h2>
   <div class="svg-wrapper">
     <svg height="40" width="150" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
    <rect id="shape" height="40" width="150" />
    <div id="text">
      <a href="web.html"><span class="spot"></span>Learn More</a>
    </div>
    </svg>
   </div>      
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
<div class="second-section">
 <div class="split left">
   <div class="centered">
  <img src="Assets/coding.png" alt="Online World">
  <h2>Website Developer</h2>
  <div class="svg-wrapper">
    <svg height="40" width="150" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
   <rect id="shape" height="40" width="150" />
   <div id="text">
     <a href="web.html"><span class="spot"></span>Learn More</a>
   </div>
    </svg>
   </div>    
   </div>
 </div>


   <div class="split center">
    <div class="centered">
   <img src="Assets/technician.png" alt="Online World">
   <h2>ICT Technician</h2>
   <div class="svg-wrapper">
     <svg height="40" width="150" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
    <rect id="shape" height="40" width="150" />
    <div id="text">
      <a href="web.html"><span class="spot"></span>Learn More</a>
    </div>
     </svg>
    </div>    
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="split right">
    <div class="centered">
   <img src="Assets/shield.png" alt="Security">
   <h2>Security Analyst</h2>
   <div class="svg-wrapper">
     <svg height="40" width="150" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
    <rect id="shape" height="40" width="150" />
    <div id="text">
      <a href="web.html"><span class="spot"></span>Learn More</a>
    </div>
    </svg>
   </div>      
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: I feel like an idiot :/ I have entered exactly what you added in your answer and I just get this.. https://gyazo.com/5f16c6207ff10c20c5ab555361c8da02

All Page HTML: https://pastebin.com/aD0SEt6K
ALL CSS: https://pastebin.com/hj0BfhHa

Comment: Use proper word while answering and posting questions. Keep in your mind.